Why is assigning a temporary value to a const ref allowed?
I've inherited a codebase with a fondness for const references. I found a devilish bug and am wondering how it ever slipped past the compiler. My C++ is super rusty, so I would appreciate some guidance.
As a MRE, suppose you have a struct and a function that returns an instance by value:
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Data;

Data Make_Data(int aVal)
{
    Data ret = { aVal, 2*aVal };
    return ret;
}

It is illegal to pass that to a method expecting a reference:
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Data& theData) : data(theData) {};
    
    Data& data;
};

int main()
{
  Bar *bar1 = new Bar(Make_Data(5)); //error: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
}

But legal if it's a const ref:
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Data& theData) : data(theData) {};
    
    const Data& data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo *foo1 = new Foo(Make_Data(1));
}

The problem is, I believe, the return value of Make_Data is on the stack. A reference to that will promptly go out of scope. Sure enough, if I put this code into an online repl the data is corrupted for certain optimisation settings.
I understand the various arguments for pass by value vs pass by const ref. But I suppose I'm missing the bit about why it's okay to pass a return value (which is a temporary, right?) as a const reference. Not from an for-optimal-performance point of view, but from why-at-all point of view. Is this a unique use-case for a const, where it prevents an additional full copy but still enables individual field access? Or just a case of caveat emptor?
By the way, I think another way to phrase the question would be, why is the restriction on const reference lifetime expansion not enforced? I've already found myself applying Guideline C.12 a few times, but this is the first instance of "ref to temp" I've found.

Full MRE for your own experimentation if the repl link above is broken:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} Data;

Data Make_Data(int aVal, int bVal)
{
    Data ret = { aVal, bVal };
    return ret;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(const Data& theData) : data(theData) {};
    
    const Data& data;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(Data& theData) : data(theData) {};
    
    Data& data;
};

int main()
{
  Foo *foo1 = new Foo(Make_Data(1, 2));
  Foo *foo2 = new Foo(Make_Data(3, 4));
  //Bar *bar1 = new Bar(Make_Data(5, 6)); //error: candidate constructor not viable: expects an lvalue for 1st argument
  std::cout << "a=" << foo1->data.a << ", b=" << foo1->data.b << std::endl;
  std::cout << "a=" << foo2->data.a << ", b=" << foo2->data.b << std::endl;
  delete foo1;
  delete foo2;
}


Adding Foo(Data&&) = delete; would prevent your issue.

But legal if it's a const ref...  True, it is legal.  But the developer is still responsible for the lifetime implications.  The member variable will become a dangling reference as soon as the temporary is destructed.  (The special lifetime extension behavior of the const-reference to a temporary is not transitive.)

The problem in not about binding const reference to a temporary, the problem is that the constructor is trying to store that reference, which isn't obvious to the caller. A typical function requires the argument to be valid only during the call, and no longer. But Foo constructor requires the argument to be valid fot the entire lifetime of the object. Such contract comes unexpected to the user of class Foo. If absolutely required, such contract should be documented, at least. Bottom line: Implementation of Foo::Foo has poor contract, and the user of Foo has broken that undocumented contract.

Why is assigning a temporary value to a const ref allowed?  C++ is not a nanny language.  It does not protect you from yourself.  The C++ sword has many razor sharp edges, including on the handle.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  C++: the bugs practically write themselves.

That's a defect in C++ that cannot be fixed, it is there for backwards compatibility with c++98, that rvalue references can be implicitly converted into a const lvalue reference .... though you can use sanitizers and valgrind to check for such bugs, they cannot be fixed without deprecating all code written in c++

@Jarod42 whoa. Is there an implicit cast to ref ref that this explicitly blocks?? @ Eljay ha, true, but syntactically why is it okay? @ igor-g ah, so const extends the lifetime through to the end of the call? That might be the key...

You could implement a destruct notifier for the Data.  q.v. https://godbolt.org/z/TPTzneo4q

theData extends the lifetime of temporary object returned by MakeData() only to the lifetime of theData itself. In this particular example, temporary returned by Make_Data() will stay valid until the end of evaluation of complete expression (that is, new Foo(Make_Data(....))). The fact that another reference is bound to the first reference doesn't extend the lifetime any more. Lifetime extension isn't transitive.

Your second version is valid from grammar point of view (it compiles), but is invalid since you program uses dangling reference - what is undefined behavior. Address sanitizer finds this issue. And Sonar Cube also finds it 37:37  ➕ Accessing a member of a reclaimed temporary (cpp:S5553) including lots of other problems.

I don't suspect that "why is it allowed" or "why is it okay" can be answered without simply reciting the standardization process.  Are you asking for the history of this feature's standardization, or are you asking why a feature would exist if it can be used dangerously?
You are describing a feature that has been proven useful, and if your point is that it can also be misused... yes, of course!  Don't write dangerous code like you show here.

@IgorG I would love a [language-lawyer] answer about the the lifetime extension not being transitive. That bit me a few months ago because I was unaware of that detail. I think it would be appropriate here if the tag gets edited in.

There is no justification from the language correctness point of view it is a bug in C++ that cannot be fixed without breaking all C++ code ever written . The language has to allow this behavior to keep c++98 code working, which has no concept of rvalue references

Language-lawyer answer; "There are five contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression.." There is no "and applies transitively to all copies of such references." The practical reason is that it is unclear how the compiler would track the temporary after the constructor returns. Does it secretly add a Data member to the Foo to hold the temporary data? (That would mean that sizeof(Foo) changes depending on how you constructed it.) What if Foo is copyable but the Data isn't?

(Indeed, the inability of class members to extend the lifetimes of temporaries is explicitly called out in 6.10: Exceptions. "A temporary object bound to a reference element of an aggregate of class type initialized from a parenthesized expression-list ([dcl.init]) persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the expression-list."

@RaymondChen 6.7.7.6 covers the situation I encountered. It was a map being passed from function to function to function to... I didn't need the map and passed {} directly, which broke down somewhere in the chain. Thank you for the citation.

But I suppose I'm missing the bit about why it's okay to pass a return value (which is a temporary, right?) as a const reference.  It's not okay to pass a return value of a temporary by const reference.  The language allows you to do it.  And you can do it safely as long as you never dereference the return value.  But if you do dereference the dangling reference, that's undefined behavior with a fully loaded footgun.  Enabling compiler warnings can help spot these code gremlins.

@DrewDormann I've nearly got the answer in these comments, just one question remains: "You are describing a feature that has been proven useful" what is the feature and why is it useful? Is it that const performs an implicit lvalue conversion in precisely this scenario, and.. maybe that's useful to extract parts of struct without copying the whole thing??

@HeathRaftery both const lvalue references and all rvalue references may bind to a temporary.  This is useful because it allows code to assign an expression that might be a reference or might be a prvalue to a variable without making a copy of it.  Note that the issue in your posted code is not that you're assigning a temporary to a reference - it's that you're holding that reference after it dangles - and that could happen with or without a temporary!

Ah, lightbulb! Simply changing const Data& data; to const Data data; is enough. In the real code, the constructor performs a very long chain of initialisers and constructors within constructors. The "magic" of lifetime extension means that the original reference remains valid all-throughout. It's only the member copy which becomes invalid. Which is hard to know when you're half a dozen constructors deep and far removed from the instantiation...


The problem is, I believe, the return value of Make_Data is on the stack. A reference to that will promptly go out of scope.

No, the problem is that the reference goes out of scope. Your phrasing suggests that going out of scope is a consequence of the problem, but it is the problem. With a small change that extends the lifetime, a value on the stack is not problematic.
int main()
{
  const Data& value_ref = Make_Data(1); // Still binding to a const reference
  Foo *foo1 = new Foo(value_ref);
  // Do stuff -- reference is valid
  delete foo1;
}

Thus, the problem is not "on the stack". The problem is "go out of scope".
Another red herring is the use of a temporary object. The dangling reference is not exclusive to temporary objects. In the above code, I gave the temporary a name, which had the side-effect of keeping the object alive. With another small change, the named object can be forced out of scope early, leaving you with the same dangling reference.
int main()
{
  Foo *foo1 = nullptr;
  {
    // This time, make `value` a non-reference so it is clearly not a
    // temporary object.
    Data value = Make_Data(1);
    foo1 = new Foo(value);
    // The non-temporary `value` goes out of scope here.
  }
  // Reference is dangling at this point.
  delete foo1; // A smart pointer would simplify this part
}

While the above is somewhat contrived, it could easily happen organically in a more complex program, especially since the Foo object is dynamically allocated (so it easily outlives the current scope).
In summary, your proposed remedy (disallow binding a temporary object to a const reference) does not address the root problems, so it would be an inadequate solution.


But I suppose I'm missing the bit about why it's okay to pass a return value (which is a temporary, right?) as a const reference.

Because it's useful. For example, if binding a temporary object to a const reference was illegal, many compound expressions – something with more than one operator — would no longer be possible without unnecessary copying of parameters.
Consider string concatenation. Let's say you have three strings that you want to combine.
  std::string hello = "Hello";
  std::string world = " world";
  std::string bang = "!";

  // Parentheses are not needed, but might add clarity.
  std::string greeting = (hello + world) + bang;

The initialization of greeting twice uses an operator+ with the following signature.
std::string operator+(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs);

This operator returns a temporary object, just like your Make_Data. So when the sub-expression hello + world is evaluated, the result is a temporary object. This temporary object becomes the first argument to the second invocation of operator+ (where the second argument is bang). That is, the temporary object binds to const std::string& lhs, while bang binds to const std::string& rhs (it is not copied). Useful and perfectly safe (because operator+ does not try to retain a reference, unlike your Foo constructor).
In other words, your proposed remedy (disallow binding a temporary object to a const reference) would cause more problems than it solves.

Great example, thank you.

Ah! It wasn't so much that I was overlooking scoping as the root cause, but actually vice-versa: that to me, creating a reference to something that has already gone out of scope (a temporary) seemed 100% undesirable. Describing this a stack issue was my crude way of illustrating that (I'm picturing a call stack, where the inner function's locals get popped off when it returns). Hence my emphasis on temp & stack. Now I realise that assigning to const ref extends the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference, which your example neatly demonstrates.

@HeathRaftery "creating a reference to something that has already gone out of scope (a temporary)" -- Your code does not do this. The reference is created before the temporary goes out of scope. The temporary exists until the semicolon at the end of the line. It exists while the constructor is executing and creating references. This is not lifetime extension. This is the normal lifetime of temporary objects.

got it! Took me a while. Finally dawned on me here. Thank you for persisting. I think a bit of my ingrained C catastrophising that has kept me safe had me unrolling the Make_Data() and Foo() calls in my head.


why it's okay to pass a return value (which is a temporary, right?) as a const reference.

the one and only reason is, backwards compatibility with C++98
take the following C++98 code
struct FOO
{
    FOO(): value(0) {}
    FOO(int value): value(value) {}
    FOO(const FOO& other): value(other.value) {}
    FOO& operator=(const FOO& other) { value = other.value; return *this; }
    int value;
};

FOO func()
{
    FOO f;
    return f; 
}

int main()
{
   FOO f1;
   f1 = func(); //operator= must bind this temporary to a const&
   return 0;
}

this is valid C++98 code and once rvalue references were introduced in C++11, the above code must still compile, you cannot just tell people they must throw away all their old code.
In an alternative universe where we can throw away billions of lines of C++ code, the above code will fail to compile, because const& shouldn't bind to temporaries, instead you would have the copy constructor use const&& and then the language should make const& implicitly convertible to const&& so you can call the copy constructor on lvalues and temporaries (because you marked it safe to do so), and then functions that accept const& won't be able to bind to temporaries, and we wouldn't have this problem (and the associated bugs) in the language.

Thanks for expanding on this point. This is a great explanation of why the feature was important in the first place (return values of operators is a prime use case), and also why we're stuck with a rather insidious capability!

This perfectly answers my why-is-this-useful question. If you can add the why-is-this-possible part then it's a complete answer for me. I understand now that the binding to const& extends the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference, which makes this sort of use case possible. Otherwise first principles tells you that func()'s local f is gone by the time it returns.

@HeathRaftery the binding to the const& in function parameters doesn't do lifetime extension, life extension only applies if this const& is a variable that exists on the same stack that contains the temporary. by default all temporaries are destroyed at the end of the full expression (the semicolon). godbolt example, except in the cases outlined by Raymond Chen, which actually state when destructors can be called before the end of the expression, which is to save stack space during arrays initialization/copying.

@HeathRaftery Otherwise first principles tells you that func()'s local f is gone by the time it returns. this is where things become much more confusing. with C++17 NRVO f should actually exist on the caller's stack, a temporary is not materialized from f instead f is already the temporary, but as NRVO is not mandatory a temporary can be materialized from it, which must obey the lifetime of temporaries by living until the end of the caller's expression, and can therefore be bound to the const& of the assignment operator, no lifetime extension happens here whatsoever.

Oh I see, I see! I've been playing with the godbolt example and gone full circle through implicit copy constructors, deleted move constructors, instrumented destructors and (N)RVO. Yes, my intuition about the stack frame and "taking a reference" has led me astray. Now I see what other commenters have been trying to teach me. No need for lifetime extension - the temporary already exists within the caller's scope. Just not after. I even found a different scenario with a local const& that demonstrates the lifetime extension principle.

I'll accept an original answer, but I want to surface the excellent learnings in the comments, as together they constitute an answer too.

Of course, just because something is legal in C++ doesn't mean it's safe! References are always in danger of becoming dangling, and the programmer must ensure lifetime.
The compiler does not bork because binding a const ref to a return value is useful behaviour - if the reference is used within the lifetime of the ~~call~~ reference, it avoids a copy. For example, this is heavily used in compound expressions like std::string joined = part1 + part2 + part3 where the second operator+ takes a const ref to the (by value) return value of the first operator+. See this answer for details.

This is explicitly (somewhat surreptitiously) enabled by the language, which extends the lifetime of the temporary bound to a reference to the lifetime of the reference itself, if necessary.


So the problem is not the binding when the constructor is called, it's the  second binding to the member variable - this does not further extend the lifetime (it is an explicit exception to lifetime extension), and once the original reference goes out of scope it's game over.

To further re-enforce this point, consider that simply changing Foo's member from const Data& data; to const Data data; resolves the issue. Even if there are other initialisations and objects within objects. The original reference survives through-out the constructor call chain, and can be used to copy construct the member without further changes.


The problem is not inherent to temporaries - any reference to something that goes out of scope is a problem that must be managed. For the general problem, Address Sanitizer (-fsanitize=address), built into GCC since v4.8, can catch it at compile time.
Assignment to const Data& works but not to Data& because an explicit rule exists that permits binding a const lvalue reference to an rvalue, to support the use cases described above and others. In C++11 rvalue references were introduced, so the rule is not necessary, but it's heavily engrained now so we're stuck with it (for good and bad) for backwards compatibility with C++98.

